# Setting breakpoints on debug console code

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

Is it possible to set breakpoints on code that was entered on chrome's or firebug's debug console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure! type this into console:

```
(function(){
    debugger;
    alert(0);
})();
```

#### [DEMO, (open up console and re-run)](http://jsfiddle.net/AR4Sa/)

Comment: Wow, great!  How did you find out?

Comment: @artistoex: experience. If I answered the question feel free to click the checkbox next to the answer.